# Sqlite Inner join repeats the same value for a particular column in each row

Tags: android, sqlite, inner-join

I am developing an application in which i tried to display the values in ledger type for which i have used inner join concepts for the two tables named daybook and tradetable.
In daybook it stores the values such as the amount the user has got ,the advance amount the user has got as well as the other details where as in tradetable it store the payment information.

Daybook table:

```
String CREATE_DAYBOOK = "CREATE TABLE " + DAYBOOK_DETAILS + "("
            + DAYBOOK_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + DAYBOOK_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOKUSER_TYPE + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_AMOUNT_IN + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_AMOUNT_OUT + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_NAME + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_MOBILENO + " NUMERIC,"
            + DAYBOOK_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
            + DAYBOOK_TYPE + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_DAYBOOK);
```

Tradetable:

```
  String CREATE_TRADE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TRADE_LABELS + "("
            + TRADE_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
            + TRADE_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_FARMERNAME + " TEXT,"
            + TRADE_FMOBILENO + " NUMERIC,"
            + TRADE_BILLNO + " NUMERIC,"
            + COCONUT_NO + " NUMERIC,"
            + COCONUT_COST + " NUMERIC,"
            + TOTAL_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC,"
            + TRADE_ADVANCE_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC,"
            + BALANCE_AMOUNT + " NUMERIC,"
            + NOTES + " TEXT,"
            + SETTLED + " TEXT" + ");";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TRADE_TABLE);
```

Query:

```
 String selectquery = "SELECT daybookdetails.date,\n" +
                 "       IFNULL(amountin,0) AS tradetotal,\n" +
                 "       IFNULL(amountout,0) AS advancetotal,\n" +
                 "       IFNULL(advanceamt,0),\n" +
                 "       daybookdescription,\n" +
                 "       daybooktype\n" +
                 "FROM farmertradelabel\n" +
                 "INNER JOIN daybookdetails ON farmertradelabel.mobileno = daybookdetails.mobileno\n" +
                 "WHERE daybookname = '"+fname+"'\n" +
                 "  AND daybookdetails.mobileno = '"+fmobno+"'\n" +
                 "GROUP BY daybookdetails.date\n" +
                 "ORDER BY daybookdetails.date ASC";
```

I have given a condition stating as follows:

```
  if (cursor.getString(3).startsWith("0")) {
                ledgerView.setBalance(cursor.getString(2));
            } else {
                double one = Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(1)) - Double.parseDouble(cursor.getString(3));
                ledgerView.setAdvancegiven(String.valueOf(one));
                ledgerView.setBalance(cursor.getString(3));
            }
```

Output which i have expected should be like this:
[image: expectedoutput]

But the output which i am getting is as follows:
[image: actualoutput]

In the Actual output the debit capital repeats the same values in each row i have tried using distinct but still it is showing the same output.can anyone tell me whats wrong in the query which i have used.

Answer (score 0):

In query you use different table and column names compared to code for creation of sql tables ...

Query is for sure not correct, you use columns from daybookdetails table not present in group by. The columns can be used with some aggregation function only like sum for example.